# Mocking static methods objects with Mockito/powermock

Tags: junit, static, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have a class DistributionRule class which contains private Set distributions;

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class DistributionRule extends BaseModel {

    private String ruleName;
    private String skuId;
    private String catalogueId;
    private String categoryId;
    private Boolean active;
    private RuleLevel level;
    private Set<Distribution> distributions;
    private Double thresholdValue;
    private RuleType ruleType = RuleType.GENERAL;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Distribution {
        private String consumerId;
        private Double distribution;
    }

}
```

In RuleServiceImpl, there is a method to get DistributionRule list:

```java
    @Override
    public List<DistributionRule> getDistributionRules() {
        return ruleRepository.findAll();
    }
```

In DivRuleApplicationTests class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class DivRuleApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private RuleServiceImpl ruleServiceImpl;
    
    @MockBean
    RuleRepository ruleRepository;
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getDistributionRulesTest(){
        Set<Distribution> distributions = new HashSet();
        when(ruleRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(Stream
                .of(new DistributionRule("rule0010", "0010", " ", " ", true, "SKU", ""), 
                    new DistributionRule("rule0020", "0020", "", "", true, "SKU", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        assertEquals(2, ruleServiceImpl.getDistributionRules().size());
        
    }

}
```

How do I pass the "Distribution" values in Stream.of()?

Comment: Why don’t you pass it with the setter? (assuming you cannot pass it with the constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the method you are trying to mock on `when`, returns a `List<DistributionRule>`. In this case, you don't need to create a `Stream.of(new DistributionRule(...))` and then collect it as a List. Simply use `List.of(new DistributionRule(...))`, as it will return the List you want it.

Secondly, you should annotate both `DistributionRule` and inner class `Distribution` with `@AllArgsConstructor` to generate a constructor with all arguments. This will let you create an DistributionRule object passing the `Distribution` Set as a parameter:

```java
@Test
public void getDistributionRulesTest(){
    Set<Distribution> distributions1 = Set.of(
        new Distribution(...), new Distribution(...)
    );

    Set<Distribution> distributions2 = Set.of(
        new Distribution(...), new Distribution(...)
    );

    when(ruleRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of(
       new DistributionRule("rule0010", "0010", ..., distributions1, ..), 
       new DistributionRule("rule0020", "0020", ..., distributions2, ...)
    ));

    assertEquals(2, ruleServiceImpl.getDistributionRules().size());
}
```

PS: I usually use the `@Data` annotation instead of `@Getter` and `@Setter`, as it's a shortcut for that and other annotations. You can take a look here if you want to know more: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment:  Also consider changing your model. I did not understand why distribution class needs to be static.